# Google Maps API - Accuracy rating. What is a High accuracy rating.

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

I'm using Google Maps V3 to get the locations from android devices running chrome.

For the most part its working fine - returning accurate results. But on rare occasions - it will record a GPS around 20 miles away.

I would like to use the `position.coords.accuracy` value to decide wether or not the gps location is trustworthy, but I cannot find any information on what a 'High' value is vs a 'Low' one..

```
function getLocation(position) {
    console.warn(position);
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

The console outputs:

> ```
> Geoposition {coords: Coordinates, timestamp: 1493214564839}
> coords>     :>     Coordinates
> accuracy>     :>     984
> altitude>     :>     null
> altitudeAccuracy>     :>     null
> heading>     :>     null
> latitude>     :>     12.2222222
> longitude>     :>     21.2222222
> speed>     :>     null
> __proto__>     :>     Coordinates
> timestamp>     :>     1493214564839
> __proto__>     :>     Geoposition
> ```

So my question is: 
What rating would equate to Trustworthy. 900? 50? 10? 2000?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#accuracy)

> The **accuracy** attribute denotes the accuracy level of the latitude and longitude coordinates. It is specified in meters and must be supported by all implementations. The value of the accuracy attribute must be a non-negative real number.

The value is in meters, you decide what is good or bad; I consider ~30 meters to be a reasonable accuracy.

Comment: just for clarification: so an accuracy of 1 in the `position.coords.accuracy` is 'within one mile' ? and the 985 that im getting currently is within 985 MILES ?

Comment: As I said in my answer, it is in meters (not sure where you got miles from).  1 would be 1 meter (which is pretty good).

Comment: Ah a silly mis-read. sorry. Thats perfect, thanks very much for your answer. I will allow up to 200 accuracy then. as that is acceptable  :)